# The autocomplete-window is not popping up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have this input which I want autocomplete with the script bellow.
The url returns a list of strings.
When I type, the data are shown in console however the autocomplete window does not pop up.

What might be wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control my-input" name="from" id="from">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#from").keyup(function (string) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/complete?station=" + $(this).val(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#from").autocomplete({
                            source: data
                        });
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `jQuery-ui.min.css`, `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js` files to the project. The following application, which I developed using mock data, works successfully. I called the `getList()` method in the error field to simulate the response from the server.

Application test image is available below:

[image]

Application source code is available below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  Input: <input type="text" id="inputElement" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)">

  <script>
    function myFunction(value) {
      /* alert(`URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/complete?station=${value}`); */
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/complete?station=" + value,
        success: function (data) {
          if (data != '') {
            $("#inputElement").autocomplete({
              source: data
            });
            console.log(data)
          }
        },
        /* I simulated the successful response from the server in the field below. */
        error: function (data) {
          $("#inputElement").autocomplete({
            source: getList()
          });
        }
      });
    }

    function getList() {
      var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure",
        "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Scala",
        "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scheme"
      ];
      return availableTags;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This did it:

```
          $("#from").autocomplete({
          source: function (request, response) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/complete?station=' + $("#from").val(),
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                      response(data);
                  },
                  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                      alert("Error");
                  }
              });
          }
      });
```

Comment: What is "this"? What did you change, and why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's a different approach I found on youtube.